# How To Describe Someone Who Is Deal-Oriented?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I'm thinking of words like fiscal, astute, shrewd, thrifty or business-savvy.

However, I know there's got to be a better word for someone who looks for great deals, a person who understands price and finds great value.

For example, a man believes his computer is not working fast anymore. He looks up prices for a new computer, costing $1200. Instead, he researches that his computer needs more memory. Rather than buying a new $1200 computer, he installs $20 of memory to make his computer work smoothly. This man is [deal oriented].

Anything along the lines of extreme financially savvy-ness is great. Another way to think about it is someone who can create something from nothing, or can do a lot with very little.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with "making deals".  What you describe is simply being a savvy consumer.

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess I'm looking for something more value-driven which creates great deals or circumstances.

Comment: perhaps meticulous ?

Comment: When someone talks to me about "great deals" I make it a point to count my fingers after shaking their hand.

Comment: @JonSnow'spapa, meticulous is more detailed about everything. I'm looking for something geared towards financial means. Great suggestion though.

Comment: Perhaps, this person has "business sense".

Comment: @Graffito, exactly. I just need that in one word :-)

Comment: _Frugal_ and _bargain hunter_ address the aspect of saving money.  _Miserly_ and _penny-pinching_ are strongly pejorative. _Resourceful_ speaks to the _repair rather than replace_ strategy.  _Cluey_ is on target for both senses, but is informal.  It may also be less common except among Australian English speakers.  (Wonderful word, I think.  The opposite of _clueless_.)

Comment: @PresterJohn, I think you got it. Resourceful. It takes care of the deal-oriented, value creating and financial aspects. I like that best.

Comment: Basically you want some synonym of *thrifty* or *frugal*, which are the positive-connotation cousins in the *cheap* constellation of words. A thesaurus will provide a comprehensive listing of synonyms, and you can refine from there. Having said that, certain cultures have their own terms: Bob Villa from *This Old House* used the term "Yankee ingenuity" when referring to cost-saving carpentry solutions, particularly those involving re-use of existing materials (because Yankees were parsimonious), and my Slavic friends make frequent reference to "Soviet solutions" (jury-rigged on the cheap).

Comment: @DomainsFeatured Hello and welcome to EL&U. In the phrasing of your question, your term *deal* seems to carry the *negotiations* sense. I've edited your question to try to emphasise the *bargains* sense, which is what I think you're after. Please feel free to [edit] further or if it wasn't what you're after, to [roll back](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/350038/revisions).

Comment: Actually, you're not describing a bargain hunter or a negotiator, but rather someone who uses their money carefully, balancing expenditure with the underlying reason for spending in the first place. I think 'deal' might not be quite the right word here, but that's the point of the question.

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=frugal)

Comment: When I read "someone who is deal-oriented" in the question title, I thought you meant "someone who considers everything like a transaction" but from the question body it looks like you mean instead "someone who is penny-wise, parsimonious, and efficient"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Oxford Dictionaries](http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resourceful) website gives as the meaning of *resourceful*:

> Having the ability to find quick and clever ways to overcome
> difficulties.

Although this word doesn't explicitly address the idea of frugality and the search for cost effective solutions that is part of your question, we can, I think, imagine that the difficulties overcome might well include budgetary ones.  And the ability to upgrade rather than replace aging technology can certainly be called *resourcefulness*.

Answer (score 2):

**"a value-conscious shopper"** is a buyer who seeks best prices.

> - Being [**price conscious**](http://www.mbaskool.com/business-concepts/marketing-and-strategy-terms/10980-price-conscious.html) means knowing how much an item would cost and avoiding buying things which are expensive for them. They generally see value for money and are value conscious too. They seek lowest price for the products they buy. They are a segment of buyers. They always lookout for best prices.

**"a conscious consumer"** also comes to mind, and I agree it can mean different things to different people. To me it means exactly what you describe, trying to spend less without reducing the quality of your purchased product.

Comment: Hi Centaurus, I was really looking for a single word that fits all the above. I think resourceful covers it.

Comment: @DomainsFeatured  It covers anything. It's nonspecific.

Comment: In all fairness, I did ask the question and @PresterJohn did a nice job of explaining how it specifically covers my description. Also, I think it nicely spans what I asked "Anything along the lines of extreme financially savvy-ness is great. Another way to think about it is someone who can create something from nothing, or can do a lot with very little. "

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe you need to provide more context.
You are searching for an esoteric word (if it exists), while providing an unequal measure of specificity.

I infer the word that best describes this type of individual is "efficient", or maybe"opportunist". However, I submit those with an assumption, that is:

- The individual who bought the RAM rather than a new device, did so in a manner which was optimal for his time to cost ratio. That is to say, his quantified effort into research, learning, purchasing, manual installation etc... did not out weight the cost of the new device.

Though the nature of the hypothetical is trivial (researching and replacing RAM). There are cases in which it is not; e.g. replacing the broken screen on an iPhone (manually), may not be as efficient as paying a third-party (at higher cost) to  provide the repair.

Comment: Ealianias, it's just an example, not all encompassing by any means. I like your time-cost take on it. Indeed, someone who is efficient with time and aware of the costs while making the most of any situation...is resourceful :-)

Comment: Resourceful is far more accurate, I myself had a hard time thinking of a word that fit. I became too focused on the example.